opendkim service not available
Hi
on Debian 12 i installed opendkim by
$ apt install opendkim opendkim-tools 

I also did apt update and apt upgrade, configured everything and was able to generate the private and public keys and everything looks fine.
Problem
With systemct list-units i cannot find any service with name opendkim installed and therefore i cannot start it.
Thanks,
Chris

There was something wrong with the installation. I removed the package with apt remove opendkim and reinstalled and the service was there.
